# I am an ocean of scalding ice - What am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, science, homonym

Here's an easy one:

> I am an ocean of scalding ice with seven siblings and many children,
>
> My fork is not for eating with and I like ponies!

**What am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Neptune, god of freshwater and the seas?

I am an ocean of scalding ice with seven siblings and many children,

> Neptune the literal planet, 1 of 8 ( 7 sisters), which has 14 known moons (many children). It's also an ice giant, but it has a temperature that is far from scalding, so I'm lost on that bit...

Wikipedia Quote:

> "The mantle is equivalent to 10 to 15 Earth masses and is rich in water, ammonia and methane.[1] As is customary in planetary science, this mixture is referred to as icy even though it is a hot, dense fluid. This fluid, which has a high electrical conductivity, is sometimes called a water–ammonia ocean."

My fork is not for eating with

> His trident which makes lasagna eating tough,

and I like ponies!

> He's patron of horse-racing,

Comment: This is a good answer, I suspect you may be correct

Comment: Yeah.. the answer makes a lot of sense. I too feel he might be correct

Comment: The [*ices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatiles) in an [(whisper)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_giant) are mostly beneath the cold exterior. Temparatures [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neptune#Internal_structure) are indeed very high.

Comment: I think it's correct, as your last question was about Mercury.

Comment: Edited with "ocean of scalding ice" explanation

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Knight of Chess.

I am an ocean of scalding ice with seven siblings and many children,

> "ocean of scalding ice" not sure but when a Knight moves, it causes 'chills in spine' of the opponent. 
>  "seven sibling" : 7 other pieces in the same rank. And "many children" : the pawns 0:)

My fork is not for eating with and I like ponies!

> [The fork of Knight](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(chess)) is a famous move which cause multiple pieces of the opponent under danger (obviously can't be eaten).
>  Ponies, well that might be because, here in India(where Chess originated), Knight is called *Ghoda* (Hindi for Horse), so ;)

Comment: First off, Love the idea +1;  Secondly, some really good connections - ponies check, fork check (and educational), siblings and children check-check;  Thirdly however, not the correct answer and not a great fit at all on the ocean of scalding ice (sorry);  And lastly, let's not get into what is believed (by some) to be originated where!  haha.

Comment: Ohh. and a bit awkward formatting, was using android app! Although wikipedia is not considered a good sources to cite, but in [case of Chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess#History), [it is very much accurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_chess#Origin), :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are

> A Cliff

I am an ocean of scalding ice with seven siblings and many children,

> The Seven Siblings may mean the Seven Sisters of Sussex(The Chalk Cliffs)

My Fork is not for eating with and I like ponies

> Fork might mean the peak of the cliff. Ponies were used in Great Britain..

---

**EDIT:


ALTERNATE ANSWER**


I think you are

> A mountain

I am an ocean of scalding ice with seven siblings and many children,

> Mountains generally have glaciers and the seven siblings may refer to seven sister hilly states in India.

My Fork is not for eating with and I like ponies

> Again, Fork for the peak of the mountain...

Comment: That would require much more specialist knowledge than my answer I think.  Very nice though. +1

Comment: Am I close or do I need to think out of the box??

Comment: You're miles away.  Sorry.

Comment: What about the alternative one? Still miles away??

Comment: Sorry.  No closer than before.

Comment: Please post the alternate answer as a separate answer so we can vote on it (and perhaps accept it) separately.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Music

?

I am an ocean of scalding ice

> Music often evokes intense emotions in listeners

with seven siblings

> 7 base notes, A B C D E F G, or do re mi fa sol la si, depending on your country/language

and many children

> Combining the notes lets people compose many different songs

My fork is not for eating

> Tuning fork

and i like ponies

> No idea.

Comment: Not the answer.  I like the idea though +1

Answer (score 0):

> I think that you are Neptune.
>  Scalding ice - the planet's surface (extreme cold and pressure creating ammonia crystals etc.)
>  Seven siblings - seven planets.
>  Many children - 67 known moons.
>  Fork - trident (now Jupiter is the god, not the planet).
>  Ponies - hippocamps that pull Jupiter's chariot.

My apologies to the earlier person with the same guess. I somehow managed to miss it before I answered.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.  Please use spoiler formatting when submitting answers.